Github actions job being cancelled due to (likely) concurrency issues?
Here is my workflow file:
name: Run Tests

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
            - 'dev'
            - 'unstable'

jobs:
    run-unit-tests:
        concurrency:
            group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}-${{ matrix.os }}
            cancel-in-progress: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'users/')}}
        runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
        strategy:
            matrix:
                os: [[A], [B, C]]
                python-version: ['3.8']


Obviously the job is being cancelled due to something related with concurrency but I can't tell what. It has to be something related to the fact that I specify two possible github runner groups (B, C) as the second "os" to test on, but am I just not able to use concurrency anymore if I want to aggregate resources from more than one runner group, or what do I add to my concurrency string to make this work?¥
